# Electron.js ipcMain send message

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, message

I am developing an electron.js application. I can easily send a message via ipcRenderer as below.

```
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', args)
```

By sending messages in this way, I can collect messages via ipcMain as follows.

```
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {})
```

So far so good. However, when I try to send a message from ipcMain to ipcRenderer, the send method does not work. I can only send a message in response to a sent message.

```
event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', res);
```

I could not send a message to ipcRenderer in any way without the event value.
I tried to listen to the page continuously with Setinterval, but it tires the system too much.
Is there any way I can send a message to ipcRenderer via ipcMain without setting up a websocket system?

Answer (score 0):

You send a message to the renderer by means of the renderer's web contents.  `event.sender` is same as the renderer's `webContents`.

So, in order to send a message to the renderer process without the `event` value, you can use the `webContents` of the window created in main.  e.g.:

```
// in main
const mainWin = new BrowserWindow({// window properties});

... 

mainWin.webContents.send('some-channel', args);
```

or if you have more than one UI window (renderer process), you can get the one you want to send to from its ID.  This also does not require you to have the `event` value

```
const winId = // some function to get the id of the correct browser window

const contents = BrowserWindow.fromId(winId).webContents;

contents.send('some-channel', args);
```

In most cases, though, I find that I end up using something like the two-way process you described above.  Usually things are starting in the renderer process, because that is where the user does something on the UI.  That sends a message back to main, and then `event.sender` can be used to send back to the renderer.